# How to get a near match of a string from a file in shell scripting?

Tags: string, shell, loops, comparison, ksh

I have a file file1.txt with 5 lines & 1 column.

Another file file2.txt with 10 lines & 5 columns.

The requirement is to get a near match for each value in file1.txt with col1 values in file2.txt.

**For Example :**

**file1.txt**

col

ABCD

BCDE

**file2.txt**

col1   col2  col3   col4   col5

ABDEF  RAMQ  0.883  98.08  CHAN

ABBDO  NFST  0.234  96.01  BANG

BCDZX  UJST  0.173  99.03  CHEN

BCHTC  OTEG  0.723  91.07  CHIN

ABCTU  HJRP  0.358  94.09  DELH

### Expected Output :

col  col1   col2  col3   col4   col5

ABCD  ABCTU  HJRP  0.358  94.09  DELH

BCDE  BCDZX  UJST  0.173  99.03  CHEN

I tried using looping logic but I was not able to get the desired output.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can't fool us that easily. There are 3 lines, not 5, in `file1.txt` and 6 lines, not 10  in `file2.txt`, and neither of the two final lines of expected output even occur in the input.

Comment: Mark, as I have mentioned it is an example of file1.txt & file2.txt. Also why do say that the neither of the lines occur in output? You can see that the value under col in final output is nothing but the file1.txt values, also the near match for this with respect to col1 from file2.txt is present.